# Indentation error - Django, on trying to resolve unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert' error

Tags: django, indentation

I have the following code, and on looking up possible solutions tried to resolve the problem by using the replacement code, but have a persistent indentation error and I cannot seem to see why, as the indentation is correct.

**Original code (which works with no errors on running server) but causes the force_insert error.**

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self):
        super().save()

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

**Replaced with:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300,300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)'
```

On running the second bit of code in models.py, i get the following error in the server

```
 File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\DjangoFacebook\pseudofacebook\users\models.py", line 24
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

I tried running makemigrations and migrate, in case something was wrong on the execution front, but the same error persists (slightly different)

```
 File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\DjangoFacebook\pseudofacebook\users\models.py", line 14
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
                                   ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

**Question:** I'd like to be able to register succesfully and remove the 'force_insert' error and subsequently not have the indentation error that results when I use the solutions that have been suggested in other posts/stack overflow questions.

The error comment seems to suggest there is something wrong with indentation at this line:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
```

but...as far as I can see, there is nothing wrong here. I've also double checked the line before, but can't see that I've done anything incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer, and am posting it here in the hope it will help someone. The problem WAS with the indentation but it wasn't evident in the IDE I was using (Notepad ++). In Notepad++ the indentation looked perfect.

I happened to open the models.py file using python itself (IDLE) and could only then see that the indentation was entirely off. I fixed it here, and then ran the server again with no errors.

It's the small things.......!